# How to check li classname is set using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

```
<li><a class="" href="/apps/financials" title="Financials">Financials</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/apps/financials" title="Financials">Financials1</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/apps/financials" title="Financials">Financials2</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/apps/financials" title="Financials">Financials3</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/apps/financials" title="Financials">Financials4</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/apps/financials" title="Financials">Financials5</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/apps/financials" title="Financials">Financials6</a></li>
```

I have set of li's like above. I need to check for all the li's classname is set or not..if not set i need to set classname as "selected" for last li.

How can i do that?

thanks 
Ravi

Comment: Are you looking for a specific class in the classname of the other LI's, or just whether that have any class set?

Comment: no i need to check if li's classname set or not..then set classname for last li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!$("li").hasClass("selected")) {
    $("li:last").addClass("selected");
}
```

Comment: In this way if `selected` is not the class it will assign the class, but OP want to assign the class iff there is no class.

Comment: i use,
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
if (!$(".cnt_left ul li a").hasClass("selected")) {
    $(".cnt_left ul li:last a").addClass("selected");
}

});
</script>

its not working...

Comment: @Ravichandran [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/s9WtZ/3/). **BUT** you're adding the class to the `<a>` element, as well as checking the class of the `<a>` element.

Answer (score 0):

try [.hasClass();](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
if ($("li").hasClass("someClass")){
    //yes it includes this class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider that we have all the `LI`s in a `OL` having `class="myOL"`

```
var lastLI = $('.myOL > li:last');
if( ! ( lastLI ).attr(class) ){
    lastLI.addClass("selected");
}
```

Comment: He wants to set the class 'selected' on the last LI only if none of the other LI's have a class set.  This code will set the last LI to selected if it doesn't have a class already, it's not doing anything with the other LI's

Comment: That's what OP said, that if the class is not set he wants to set the class on the last LI

Comment: No, he said he want to "check all the li's classname and if not set" set the last LI to selected.

Comment: confusion confusion confusion, Any why that's what i got from OPs requirement. The other way also been posted and accepted. Chill.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to store if you found a classname on an LI

Loop the LI's using jquery's Each, if the elements attribute class is blank, set your variable to true

After the loop, if your variable is true, set li:last to be 'selected'

Rough example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var liHasClass = false;
  $('Selector > li').each(function () {
    if($(this).attr('class') != '') {
      liHasClass = true;
    }
  });
  if(liHasClass == false) {
    $('selector li:last').addClass('selected');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand, but I'll take a shot:

The following will add the class `selected` to the *last* `<a>` element *if* no `<a>` element already has the `selected` class.

```
var $anchors = $('li a');
if ($anchors.filter('.selected').length < 1) {
    $anchors.last().addClass('selected');
}
```

---

**Alternative interpretation**
If the `class` attribute is empty (or not set) for *all* `<li>` elements, add class `selected` to last `<li>` element:

```
if ($('li').filter(function() {
        return this.className && this.className.length > 0; // Include all elements with `.className` set and non-empty.
    }).length < 1) {
    $('li:last').addClass('selected');
}
```

- [Demo with no classes](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/xfz7g/): `.selected` is added,
- [Demo with class on any `<li>`](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/xfz7g/1/): nothing's changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to test a class you can use .hasClass()
http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

If you don't know what class you are testing for this wont work though.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$('li').attr(class)){
    $('li:last').addClass("selected");}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
$(function(){
 if (!$('li.selected').length >0)
    $('li:last').hasClass('selected');
});
```